# What is the most efficient method to a rounding double?

Tags: java, compare, double

I am looking to round a double (for hashcode method mainly). This is critical for my project even if it is a simple method. Currently my method is the following :

```
private final static int _STEP = 5;
private final static double _RANGE = Math.pow(10, -_STEP + 1);
private final static double _GAP = Math.pow(10, _STEP - 1);/**
 * @param d
 * @return the current d with a static constant number of
 *         decimals
 */
public strictfp static double roundDoubles(double d) {
    double tamp = d * _GAP;
    tamp = Math.round(tamp);
    tamp = tamp * _RANGE;
    if (tamp == -0.0) {
        return 0.0;
    }
    return tamp;
}
```

This method permit to round a double at `1/(10^5)`. I don't really care about the fact that the precision is in decimal . You can round it in binary this is not a issue (for example round by  `1/(2^13)` is almost equivalent).

I guess that we can probably do something very efficient with the method `Double.doubleToLongBits(value)` and analyzing the long but I am not specialist in it.

Thanks a lot,

Eliott

Comment: Do you *really* need something "more efficient"? When you profiled your code, was this actually the most significant performance bottleneck?

Comment: This method is 22.7 percent of the total time of my process according to visualVM. I guess I can try to use it less but I already make some improvements on it.

Comment: In fact, it is not a absolute needing, it works. But 22 percent is the most expansive part of my code so if I can improve it would be cool. :)

Comment: Well, that does sound significant, assuming you're doing representative work, and your JIT is all warmed up etc. How much time do your proposed alternatives take?

Comment: Another thought: are you repeatedly rounding the same numbers? Could you cache the rounded number (or the hash code) to avoid recalculation?

Comment: I already cache the hashcode but in many classes, My solution take 5 ns to solve.